# Getting one or two words out of a string

Tags: r, json

My Dataset has a colum with categories formatted like this:

> {"id":42,"name":"Pop","analytics_name":"Pop","slug":"music/pop","position":14,"parent_id":14,"parent_name":"Music","color":10878931,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/music/pop"}}}

or this

> {"id":313,"name":"Small Batch","analytics_name":"Small Batch","slug":"food/small batch","position":10,"parent_id":10,"parent_name":"Food","color":16725570,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/food/small%20batch"}}}

I now want to rename these to "Pop" and "Small Batch" using this code:

`DatasetNew %>% mutate(category = str_extract(category, regex('(?<={"id":.,"name":"|"id":..,"name":"|"id":...,"name":").+(?=","analytics_name")')))`

When testing the regex code on a external site it worked, but it I cant get it to work in RStudio.

Comment: You want to **extract** those strings or **replace** them with some other strings? And what is your expected output?

Comment: I want to replace the original string in the colum, with the extracted string. So my expected Output would be a colum with "Pop" or "Small Batch" respectivly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My regex code was wrong. In R you have to double escape {.

Solution:

`datasetNew %>% mutate(category = str_extract(category, regex('(?<=\\{"id":.,"name":"|"id":..,"name":"|"id":...,"name":").+(?=","analytics_name")')))`